# Porque não recebi a minha medalha?

Tags: suporte

Algum tempo atrás eu cumpri a tarefa da **"medalha Entusiasta"**, porém a mesma não foi computada em meu perfil e percebi que a pontuação da mesma está contando novamente.

O que está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A medalha é dada para quem teve 30 dias **consecutivos** de acesso conforme imagem abaixo, e conforme o calendário de acesso do seu perfil você tem vários dias sem ter feito acesso por isso toda vez que fica um dia sem acessar a contagem dos consecutivos começa de novo, lembrando que o acessado só conta dentro do período UTC e precisa ser computada alguma atividade, só ler o site não gera atividade. Então sua nova chance é daqui a 20 dias se não falhar mais nenhum dia.

[image: Calendário de acessos][image: Calendário de acessos][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá meu amigo Manieiro, então daqui a "20 dias" eu preciso ter alguma ação no site é isto?

Comment: Não, você precisa ter ação todos os 20 dias seguidos para ganhar a medalha.